# PostgreSQL query returning multiple rows based on id

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to figure out how I can select multiple rows from a table, based on the id column.
Something like this:

```
select * from table where id=1 or id=2 or id=3
```

Should I loop through every id and perform a query for each iteration?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
select *
from table
where id in (1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to have results where `id = 1` and results where `id = 2` and results where `id = 3`, you have to use a different logic.

You actually want results where `id = 1 or id = 2 or id = 3`

Or you want results where `id in (1, 2, 3)`

Or you want results where `id between 1 and 3`